# Can we say "Let's have a beer meanwhile they play tennis"?

Tags: adverbs

I am a bit confused on how to use "meanwhile". I know you can use it as a connector. *Meanwhile*, I did not notice

I see [dictionary.com says](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/meanwhile?s=t):

> noun
>
> 1. meantime.
>
> adverb
>
> 2. in the intervening time; during the interval.
> 3. at the same time:
>      *Meanwhile, the others were back home enjoying themselves.*

I assume this is fine:

> Let's have a beer. Meanwhile, they will be playing tennis

But I wonder, can you use it like this?

> Let's have a beer meanwhile they play tennis

Comment: No, in that case it is "let's have a beer while they play tennis".

Comment: @JustinYoung thanks! So "meanwhile" is to be used just in the beginning of a sentence?

Comment: No, *meanwhile* can be used in the middle of a sentence.  It just has a different meaning to *while*.

Comment: You can say that but it would be unusual for a native speaker to say it. A more plausible sentence would be *Let's have a beer, and meanwhile they play tennis.*

Comment: This is a really good question.  As a native speaker, I know that you can't use *while* and *meanwhile* in the same way, but it's very hard for me to explain exactly *why*.

Comment: @User1 you seem to be posting lots of "answers" as comments - this comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the Lucian Sava pointed *meanwhile* is an adverb, here I want to point a difference in their usage and meaning.

According to Longman:

> **while** :  **during** the time that you are doing something, or **something** is happening.
>
> **meanwhile** :  **at the same time** as **something else** is happening.

As you see, **meanwhile** is used for **two** concurrent activities:

> **Let's have a beer**. Meanwhile, **they will be playing tennis**.
>
> **Let's have a beer**, and meanwhile **they will be playing tennis**.

In the sentence above both activities are important to be mentioned. You inform the hearer about two activities.

but **while** is used to focus on **one activity** that is happening during another activity.

> **Let's have a beer** while they play tennis.

In the sentence above you mainly want to say "let's have a bear", but you also add that you do this while they play tennis.

Comment: You know what? Let's not have a bear.

Comment: @KyleHale Sorry! I didn't get your sentence! is it a kidding?!

Comment: I think he's referring to the fact that the last sentence in your answer uses 'bear' in the quote instead of 'beer'.

Comment: And just FYI, it's "are you kidding" or "was that a joke", as opposed to "is it a kidding".

Comment: @Texenox lol, right!! however, bears are nice too.

Answer (score 8):

As regards your first example:

> Let's have a beer. Meanwhile, they will be playing tennis.

your assumption is correct. There are two distinct clauses, **meanwhile** is correctly used as an adverb.

In your second example:

> Let's have a beer meanwhile they play tennis.

the use of **meanwhile** is incorrect. The two clauses should be separated by a subordinate conjunction that introduces the subordinate clause. Obviously this conjunction, in this context, is **while**. This said, the correct sentence would be:

> Let's have a beer while they play tennis.

However, as User1 pointed out in their comment:

> Let's have a beer and meanwhile, they play tennis.

is also correct. Here, the two clauses joined by the conjunction **and** are both independent clauses, where **meanwhile** is again correctly used as an adverb.

Comment: 'Let's have a beer, and meanwhile they play tennis.' Shouldn't that be 'and meanwhile, they'll play tennis"?

Comment: I think you're [right](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/owlprint/607/): 2. Use commas after introductory a) clauses, b) phrases, or c) words that come before the main clause, @Kevin. :)

Comment: I was actually talking about they play vs they'll play.  Adding the comma was an unconscious correction.

Comment: @Kevin Since Lucian Sava is referring to my comment, I'll reaffirm that either *they play* or *they'll play* works. *They'll* would probably be more common in this context, but *they* is also possible.

Comment: That last sentence still sounds awkward to me as a native speaker. I can't put my finger on why it sounds wrong, though. Is it correct to use that tense of "play" to describe an ongoing action? "Will be playing" or "are playing" make it sound more natural to me.

Comment: whether or not either of these sentences are technically correct, they are decidedly NOT idiomatic English.

Answer (score 0):

The current answers explain it better in the English-grammar sense, but I thought this example may help clarify some confusion on how a native speaker means to use it.

> "*meanwhile*", is used as a short form of "*in the mean-time*".
>
> Restated: "*during that [difference of] time*"

> Let's have a beer. [**meanwhile / during that time**], they will be playing tennis
>
> Let's have a beer during that time they play tennis. - *stringed together fragments, doesn't work*
>
> Let's have a beer and [**meanwhile / during that time**], they will play tennis. *Technically works - but "Let's have a beer while they play tennis" still sounds better because it is easier to phrase and shorter.*