# Why "as" is used instead of "meanwhile"?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117951/synopsis):

> Renton suggests to Spud that they steal the money and run **as** Begbie & Sick Boy get drinks in.

Why "as" is used instead of "meanwhile"?

Comment: See http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/73217/37009 .

Comment: You could say **and meanwhile** there instead of **as**. But **and** would be needed. See Lucian Sava's remarks about conjunctions at the answer pointed to by the link above.

Answer (score 1):

**As** and **meanwhile** are different grammatical objects: the former is a conjunction, while the latter is an adverb. In other words, they *are not* interchangeable in your sentence. Please notice that in your sentence, *as* could be changed for *while* (not *meanwhile*).

I should suggest if this is not the case yet that you get some theoretical knowledge about the difference between a conjunction and an adverb, for the construction of phrases may depend on those concepts.